# How to get status code of HttpCall with Ktor and kotlinx serialization

Tags: ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to figure out how to check the http status code of a http request with `Ktor`

I have a simple GET request like this with a HttpResponseObject that holds the data the server returns and any errors server side that I control

```
val response:HttpResponseObject<MyObject> = client.get<HttpResponseObject<MyObject>>(url)
```

Now what I need to also be able to check are is if there are unhandled exceptions or Authentication exceptions that get thrown by the server. In these cases nothing would be returned by the server and a status code of 500 or 401 error would be returned.

I see the documentation has you can get the full http response with something like this

```
val response:HttpResponse client.get(url)
```

but then how do lose my serialized data coming back and I couldnt find any examples on how to serialize it from the `HttpResponse` object.

Does anyone have any suggestions? is there a way to get the http status code from my first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the `HttpResponseValidator` in the `HttpClientConfig` to catch the status codes then throw exceptions

```
HttpResponseValidator{

            validateResponse { response: HttpResponse ->
                val statusCode = response.status.value
                when (statusCode) {
                    in 300..399 -> throw RedirectResponseException(response)
                    in 400..499 -> throw ClientRequestException(response)
                    in 500..599 -> throw ServerResponseException(response)
                }

                if (statusCode >= 600) {
                    throw ResponseException(response)
                }
            }
        }
```

By doing so I was then able to pass the error through my custom object back up to the UI

```
private suspend fun getCurrentWeatherForUrl(url:String, callback: (HttpResponseObject<MyObject>?) -> Unit){
        var response:HttpResponseObject<MyObject>? = null
        response = try{
            client.get<HttpResponseObject<MyObject>>(url){
                header("Authorization", "Bearer $authKey")
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            HttpResponseObject(null, e.toString())
        }

        callback(response)
    }
```

Also you can use `HttpResponse.receive()` to get a serialized object AND the response data

```
val response:HttpResponse = client.get(url)
val myObject:MyObject = response.receive<MyObject>()
```

Comment: What is HttpResponseObject?

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the status code by using the following code:
`val response = client.get<HttpResponse>(url)` after that, to get the bytes from the response and serialize it you can try using `val bytes: ByteArray = response.readBytes()`

You can find full documentation here :
https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/quick-start/responses.html

Comment: Yeah but then How do I deserialize the data into my object?

Comment: Depends. If the status code is returned as plain text you have but to decode the bytes using utf-8 or ASCII and copy the string in your class.

Comment: Looking further that HttpResponse is deprecated for this https://api.ktor.io/1.3.2/io.ktor.client.statement/-http-response/index.html which only has a `ByteReadChannel`

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponse` is deprecated, you need to use `HttpStatement` and then get the status after calling `execute()` on it.